# How to delete tiny elements of anchored letters from PDF to word converter

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, layout

I am translating a document which I originally got as a PDF. The PDF to Word converter left lots of tiny elements anchored to the document, many of which appear to be outlines of letters that the algorithm recognized as small image elements rather than letters for some reason.

Is there any way I can select/cycle through them to determine whether it needs to be deleted? There are also tables, and I do not want to delete those. It is a 60-page document so this would save me a lot of time.

[I can highlight the text, which captures the anchored elements but they are difficult to isolate and capture without deleting text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdCBO.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looking at your example I can't say this sounds promising, but how about you re-OCR the PDF and see if that does a better job of recognition than the first scan/OCR? Otherwise, what if you had a bit of VBA that could hide/show all the images anchored to a paragraph, so that with a couple of keys you could toggle the images on and off. Would that help?

Comment: I think that would, though I would have to research Word VBA and its implementation. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

To do those kind of things, you could start with two small VBA macros along the following lines:

```
Sub hidepictures()
Dim p As Word.Paragraph
Dim shp As Word.Shape
Dim ishp As Word.InlineShape
With Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
  For Each shp In .ShapeRange
    shp.Visible = msoFalse
  Next
  For Each ishp In .InlineShapes
    ishp.Range.Font.Hidden = True
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub hidepictures()
Dim p As Word.Paragraph
Dim shp As Word.Shape
Dim ishp As Word.InlineShape
With Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
  For Each shp In .ShapeRange
    shp.Visible = msoFalse
  Next
  For Each ishp In .InlineShapes
    ishp.Range.Font.Hidden = True
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

and assign a keystroke to each one. Then modify them as you go along. Or you might prefer to hide pictures associated with the Selection rather than the first paragraph in the selection.

For the "inline pictures" part to be effective, you would have to ensure that Hidden Text is not set to be visible.

There are some instructions about how to install VBA macros on Windows versions of Word [here](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm)